# Likelihood ratio for the Normal distribution with known variance

Tags: probability

I found out that the likelihood ratio test is equal to this $\lambda = exp(-\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^n (Y_i- \mu_0)^2 + \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=0}^n (Y_i- Y bar )^2)  $

The question asks us to show ask us to derive the rejection region for this test and show that this test is based on the same test statistic as for a hypothesis test on $µ$ when $σ^2$ is known this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: You might want to check your expression, including signs and subscripts

Comment: Yeah. I forgot to add a minus in front of the equation. But still having issue with the problem. I tried to multiply it out and take the ln but it didn't seem to help.